# Why do Enums require (store) a tag?

Tags: enums, rust

From the [Rust-Language book,](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/book/enums.html)

> A value of an enum type contains information about which variant it is, in addition to any data associated with that variant. This is sometimes referred to as a ‘tagged union’, since the data includes a ‘tag’ indicating what type it is. The compiler uses this information to enforce that you’re accessing the data in the enum safely. For instance, you can’t simply try to destructure a value as if it were one of the possible variants:

Why do Rust Unions *require* a tag? If the compiler has sufficient internal knowledge about the enum type and constructors used in compile time, why does it have to allocate a byte for every enum value to internally store the "tag"? Is this information ever used in runtime? Do other rust types store tags?

Comment: If you have a `Result` that is either an value or an error, how could the compiler know ahead of time which it would be? What would "sufficient internal knowledge about the enum type" be?

Comment: Rust has unions, and they don't have a tag. Enums have a tag by definition; they are tagged unions.

Comment: @loganfsmyth through monomorphization -- the same way Rust handles trait-generics (which don't have a tag, right?)

Comment: If you *can* do it with traits and generics, feel free! But you can't monomorphize something whose value is unknown at compile time. That's what `enum` is for. Consider `if rand::random() { Some(10) } else { None }`.

Comment: I'm undecided on what to do with this question. It seems to be asking something along the lines of "what's the point of tagged unions" which is broad but potentially answerable, but maybe it's also asking "what's the difference between types and values" which is the kind of thing you could spend a lot of books explaining. I'm voting "too broad" -- perhaps it would help if you can give an example of code that uses an `enum` where you think it could be monomorphized?

Comment: (And to be clear, there definitely are cases where `enum` tags may be optimized away -- if the `enum` is only used in a single function, it's loaded into registers, and the tag register happens to never be needed because the different variants are only used in mutually exclusive, non-converging code paths. But I get the feeling that kind of optimization isn't what you're asking about.)

Comment: In the general case of some unspecified enum, the compiler will have no idea what variant a given variable holds, so some way to distinguish is necessary. Anything beyond that is the realm of compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

While the compiler has enough information to create any specific enum variants, you can then pass that variant as a parameter to someone who expects any possible variant of the enum.  When the value is transferred, the knowledge of the original variant is lost, especially since that same function could be called with different variants.  So, the approach is to use a tag.

Some languages use a vtable or class pointer instead of a tag, but here Rust chooses the term "tag" — however it does not say that the tag is a byte, so it *could* be implemented as a pointer.